# installing neovim plugins with no Git available

Tags: neovim

I have successfully migrated all my local configuration from vim to neovim and plugins are installed flawlessly.
Now I want to install some plugins at some servers y work every day. Those servers has no Git available and installing git is not an option, so I need to know if is there any other available procedure to move my plugins from my local folder to server and make it work

thanks

Comment: Which plug-in manager are you using, if any? Are you using NeoVim/Vim 8 native packages?

Comment: vim plug is my package manager

Comment: How about just copying plugin directory from your local machine and not running `:Plug*` commands on remotes?